# Cannot upload huge file in IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to upload a weblog file which is of size 500MB in my IPython notebook. But I get the error "Cannot upload the file >25Mb".

Is there a way I can overcome this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @AnirudhGP:

Yes instead of uploading the file, try moving the file from your local system to your folder in which your notebook is present. 

I used this command:

sudo cp /home/username/testData.tsv /home/username/DatalabCode/datalab/notebooks/Untitled\ Folder/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to upload 6 GB file also in the later version of the Anaconda Distribution, I think the same was fixed in the later versions.
I am currently using conda 4.5.11.